# R LpSolve How to optimize picks with Budget Restriction

Tags: r, optimization, restriction, lpsolve

I have a question about LpSolve in R. I have a panel with the following data: Football player ID (around 500 player), how many games each of them has already played, number of goals scored and cost of the player. I want to create a matrix from this data, but I do not know how this works with such a large amount of data (I have about 500 football  players an therefore 500 rows).

The goal is to select the optimal number of players for a budget of 1,000,000. Each player can only be selected once, optimized by the number of scored goals.

In the end I want to have the optimal selection of players which scored the most goals, and the budget has to be (almost) used up.

Since I am relatively new with R I do not know how to solve this problem with LpSolve yet and I fail at the matrix production and the constraints.

I´m very grateful for your help !

My panel looks like this (example):

footballplayerID | gamesplayed | avggoals | costsperplayer

1. 233276       |      120     |    80     |    50.000
2. 474823       |      200     |    140    |    34.000
3. 192834       |      150     |    90     |    14.000
4. 192833       |      30      |    50     |    90.000
5. 129834       |      204     |    129    |    70.000
6. 347594       |      123     |    19     |    10.000
7. 203845       |      129     |    57     |    43.000
8. 128747       |      98      |    124    |    140.000

.

.

500. 123749      |      128     |    182    |   100.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I create a df like this:
    df <- read.table(text =
    "footballplayerID | gamesplayed | avggoals | costsperplayer
    233276 | 120 | 80 | 50000
    474823 | 200 | 140 | 34000
    192834 | 150 | 90 | 14000
    192833 | 30 | 50 | 90000
    129834 | 204 | 129 | 70000
    347594 | 123 | 19 | 10000
    203845 | 129 | 57 | 43000
    128747 | 98 | 124 | 1400001", 
    header = TRUE,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    sep = "|"
    )

```
library(lpSolve)
```

The coefficients for objective function is `avggoals`:

```
obj_fun <- df$avggoals
```

The constraints is the sum of `costperplayer` that needs to be less than or equal to 100.000.000

```
constraints <- matrix(df$costsperplayer, nrow = 1)
c_dir <- "<="
c_rhs <- 1000000
```

You can then solve that lp problem with `lp()`. the argument `all.bin = TRUE` makes sure you choose a player once or not at all.

```
lp <- lp("max",
         obj_fun,
         constraints,
         c_dir,
         c_rhs, 
         all.bin = TRUE)
```

You can than have a look at the selected players:

```
df[lp$solution == 1, ]
```